# Getting connection reset by peer during TCP socket connection?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, ipc

i'm making a small client-server application,where server forks a child process after accept,for multiple connections while the client connects to it ,sends a message and receives a response. following is my code fragment:
-- client.c

char buffer[256];

```
portno=5001;    
   
   /* Create a socket point */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   
   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }
    
   
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
   
   /* Now connect to the server */
   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR connecting");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   /* Now ask for a message from the user, this message
      * will be read by server
   */
while(1)
{   
   printf("Please enter the message: ");
   bzero(buffer,256);
   fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
   /* Send message to the server */
   n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
   
   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   /* Now read server response */
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n==0)
    {
      perror("nothing to read");
    }
   
   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
   }
    
   printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

--server.c

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int n, pid;
   
   /* First call to socket() function */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   
   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   /* Initialize socket structure */
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5001;
   
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
   
   /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   /* Now start listening for the clients, here
      * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
      * for the incoming connection
   */
   
   listen(sockfd,5);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
   
   while (1) {
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL,NULL);
        
      if (newsockfd < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on accept");
         exit(1);
      }
      
      /* Create child process */
      pid = fork();
        
      if (pid < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on fork");
         exit(1);
      }
      


 if (pid == 0) 
 {
     while(1)
     {
     /* This is the client process */
     close(sockfd);
     doprocessing(newsockfd);
   /**  exit(0); **/
     }
 }
      else {
         close(newsockfd);
      }
        
   } /* end of while */
}


void doprocessing (int sock) {
   int n;
   char buffer[256];
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);
       if(n==0)
    {
      perror("nothing to read");
    }
   
   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
   
   if (n <= 0) {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
   }
    
}
```

when i run the both,O/P is following:

```
Please enter the message: arjun
I got your message
Please enter the message: gaur
ERROR reading from socket: Connection reset by peer
```

Please help.how to resolve this

Comment: You aren't closing the socket in the forked child process, and you aren't checking the return value of `recv()` for zero.

Comment: then what is close(sockfd) inside child process doing ? and i handled for recv()=0 ,but it's not printing the statement inside.i edited the code.

Comment: `close(sockfd)` is closing the listening socket. Nothing in the forked child is closing the accepted socket (`newsockfd`). You aren't handling `n == 0` in either this forked child process or the client, except to erroneously treat it as an error in the server's forked child process.

Comment: i edited the code to check for 0 , but when i ran i got the same error,none of those statements got printed,did it in both client and server when reading.

Comment: So you're ignoring the main part of my comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forked child process is exiting without closing `newsockfd`. On some platforms that causes a connection reset instead of an orderly close.

You also need to check the result of `recv()` for zero and handle it correctly, i.e. not as an error, and you also need to use a positive return value correctly, e.g. instead of

```
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

it should be

```
printf("%.*s\n",n,buffer);
```

Comment: if i close the newsockfd before the exit(0) ,then how will the client connect second time to the server when sending second set of data?

Comment: You have just exposed a flaw in your own application protocol. The server's forked child processes a single request and reply and then exits, but the client expects to be able to send multiple requests over a single connection. Either the client needs to lose its loop, or the forked child process at the server needs to use one.

Comment: the child will exit after the first run i.e receive the data,print it,write to the socket(client reads and prints),close accepted socket and exits.But i want to the child to keep running i.e socket not to get closed until client wishes to do so

Comment: @arjungaur: "*But i want to the child to keep running i.e socket not to get closed until client wishes to do so*": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718967/getting-connection-reset-by-peer-during-tcp-socket-connection#comment66740533_39720540

Comment: So, as I have already stated, the child needs a loop. It terminates when `recv()` returns zero or -1.

Comment: if the client loses the loop ,it will work fine without any error but only a single run,but i want multiple to make it work for multiple sending and receiving messages.should it work if i put an infinite loop over if(pid==0) ? i'll try

Comment: yes,you told me to either lose the loop in client,which i don't want to ,else you asked me to put a loop over forked child process

Comment: Exactly. So why are you asking me whether to put a loop into the child process? NB `read()` or `recv()` doesn't make any difference to my answer. They both return zero indicating end of stream, -1 indicating an error, or a positive integer that should be used in the way I described.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is:

1. Server starts listening.
2. Client connects to listening server.
3. Server forks of process serving client.
4. Client sends data.
5. Serving process as of 3. receives date from client and prints it.
6. Serving process as of 3. sends response to client.
7. Serving process as of 3. exists/ends and with this its accepted socket (the peer to the client) gets closed.
8. Client receives response and prints it.
9. Client tries to send more data to the serving process as of 3..
10. Client tries to read more data from the serving process as of 3..
11. Step 10. fails because the serving process as of 3. already ended (step 7.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,but when i remove that exit(0) as of 7. and make a fresh connection,even the first request is not getting processed,i get "BAD file number" ,any idea how to resolve this ,so that child serving client doesn't closes the accepted socket as long as client is done requesting?

Comment: @arjungaur: Put the code inside `doprocessing()` in a loop until a certain condition is met?

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error occurs when receiving, not when sending.

Comment: EJP is correct on this one,because if the problem was with sending then atleast the server should have printed the statement "Here is the message"  but it is not.

Comment: @arjungaur: A completed write on the sending side does not imply a completed read (for the data written) on the receiving side.

Answer (score -1):

Your client does this:

- Connect to the server
- Send some data to the server
- Receive some data from the server
- Send some data to the server
- Receive some data from the server
- ...

but your server does this (possibly with multiple connections at once):

- Wait for a connection
- Receive some stuff from the client
- Send some stuff to the client
- Close the connection (by exiting the only process that has the connection open)

So the server closes the connection when the client is about to send some more data, and the client gets an error because the server closed the connection.

You need to either make the server keep receiving and sending data in a loop (so it can happen several times on the same connection), or make the client make a new connection each time it wants to send something.

Comment: i don't think it's due to multiple connections at once,because right now i'm only connecting a single client to the server

Comment: @arjungaur I didn't say the problem was due to multiple connections at once. Read again.

Comment: yes ,i read it ,you said possibly,which is why i just  told you that to confirm that we  can cancel that one out and look for other reasons for connection getting closed.

Comment: The server never closes the connection at all, except in the forking parent. Which is the problem.

Comment: @EJP The code in the question was edited. That `while(1)` loop used  to not be there; it was `close(sockfd); doprocessing(); exit(0);` (which closes the connection by exiting).